# Need to wait for an async operation to complete before moving on in method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, maui

In the following method, I only want the null check for the `result` variable to occur after result is assigned a value. What I think is happening now is that sometimes the null check is happening before the `FilePicker.PickAsync()` is complete, so result hasn't been assigned a value. Instead, I only want the null check to happen once the user picks their file.

```
private async void PickFileButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("checkpoint1");
        FileResult result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            FileTypes = new FilePickerFileType(
                new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "public.item" } },
                    { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "*/*" } },
                    { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { "*/*" } },
                    { DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst, new[] { "public.item" } }
                })
        }); ;
        Console.WriteLine("checkpoint2");

        if (result.FileName != null)
        {
            filePath = result.FullPath;
            FilePathLabel.Text = filePath;
            Console.WriteLine(FilePathLabel.Text);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exception if file picker operation fails
        Console.WriteLine($"File picking failed: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

I'm still not entirely sure that's even the issue. It was brought to my attention because the `FilePathLabel` wasn't being updated and when I added a breakpoint, I noticed result was null sometimes. Also, this issue only happens when you first run the program and the user chooses a file. After choosing their file for the first time, if they try again, then everything seems to work which I don't understand.

Comment: Whatever is after the `await` _cannot_ occur before the task completes. That said, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.storage.filepicker.pickasync) states that this method returns "File picking result object, or null when picking was cancelled by the user.", so that's where your nulls are coming from. If you had null reference type checks turned on, you'd probably get a warning there.

Comment: What is the `filePath`? Where is it declared?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Let's not get bogged down in coding convention issues here. In any case, it's a `FileResult?`.

Comment: I don't believe that the `null` check is happening before the `FilePicker.PickAsync()` is complete. The `await` keyword *asynchronously waits* the call to complete before the execution jumps to the next line.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel `result` is null even when the user doesn't click cancel. I added a breakpoint on the Console.WriteLine("checkpoint2") line, and the file directory opens but the user can't even choose their file yet and the breakpoint has already been reached, so they haven't even had a chance to click cancel. And at that point, result is null.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin I see. Any other idea why `result` may be null?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your OS?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I'm on my mac. This method is in a .NET MAUI application but this error is occurring no matter what platform I deploy it on.

Comment: I was asking because that sounds suspciously like [a bug on macOS that will be fixed in .NET 8](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11088).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I think you might be right. Thank you!

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel it's about being able to see the type of the variable, not about coding conventions. This is not Visual Studio where you can hover the mouse over the `var` and see the type.

Comment: To clarify: if that breakpoint is reached, then PickAsync has returned. If it is returning null, but user hasn’t had a chance to pick a file, then it likely got an exception internally. The Async operation did complete; it’s just broken inside. Nothing to do but wait for a fix. That’s my interpretation of the symptom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is awaiting - just: the result is `null` (either due to cancellation or some internal failure). So: check for that:

```cs
if (result?.FileName is not null)
{
    // ...
}
```

(which is semantically similar to `if (result is not null && result FileName is not null)`)